# how to post to wall after logging in to FB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, posting

i will like to know how to post to my own wall with a string @"123456789" after logging in to FB with this

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];

    // Check and retrieve authorization information
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    // Initialize user permissions
    userPermissions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_stream", 
                                nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        //[permissions release];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following code to feed

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR MESSAGE"],
                                   @"message", nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: hi Naveen, thanks for the reply. do u know how to prefill the dialogue box ? instead of posting with out telling the user ?

Comment: @Desmond the code above will do the same it will not interact with user and just feed to the wall

Comment: In above code replace 'YOUR MESSAGE' with whatever you want to post

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own request and post it to facebook, like the following request:
you specify what you want from: type, link, picture, source, message, name, caption, description, and you must provide an access_token, which if you're using facebook api, you can get easily.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?type=&link=&picture=&source=&message=&name=jwt&caption=inmyworld&description=&access_token=